# can we create a macro in c- language without define #define

Tags: c, macros

I know that we can create a macros in c- language by using preprocessor(#define), but can we create macros with out using preprocessors i;e without #define. if there is any please help me..

Thank you

Comment: How about writing an inline function ?

Comment: Why do you need to avoid using preprocessor macros?

Comment: i Just want to know is there any possibility..

Comment: @user3046320 What are your restrictions preventing you using define?

Comment: @Nagarjun depends on what you understand of "macro"? do you mean macro as runtime shortcut? or macro as compiletime replacement? And overall: what ou want to archive by that what you call "macro"? I mean at all, a functioncall is also a macro. And that what you call define macro is simply a Preprocessor macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define macro on the command line when invoking compiler. See `-D` option of gcc. Also there are predefined macros like `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, etc.

Comment: That command line stuff is a GCC feature and nothing guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: @Lundin Command line macros are there and are very useful. They are in many compilers (maybe all). We can't deny their existence just because the C standard doesn't specify compiler parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In the standard C language, macros are created with `#define`. There is no other way.

Comment: Depends on what we call a macro. Just in view of the meaning of the word macro, even a function would be a macro. And if he is asking realy for thats, what is called Preprocessor macro. his question is senseless cause he is asking about. Macros without macros.

Comment: @Zaibis I'm referring to what the C standard calls a macro, which is everything following a `#define`. There is no formal, normative definition of the term macro in the standard, but all over the document, they use the word macro when they speak of `#define`:d items.